# duplicate documents inside the index Azure Cognitive Search after Indexer re-run on schedule

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I created an Azure Cognitive Search using a Cosmos DB SQL API database. I created the index and the indexer. My Cosmos DB database is refreshed daily. Hence, I created the indexer in my azure search to be refreshed on schedule. The problem I have now is my index. The index is duplicated and retrieves duplicate items. When I created my index I had 23,000 documents indexed and currently, I have 46,000 indexed items. My search results are duplicates. This is a production app at work, so your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `My Cosmos DB database is refreshed daily.`? Are you deleting the documents and recreating them in Cosmos DB?

Comment: Yes, The data inside each container is erased completely and replaced with new data.

Comment: I want to overwrite the index. it seems it just copied the data again when I run the scheduled indexer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the expected behavior. When an Indexer runs, it does not automatically delete the documents from an Index that are not present at the source. Only those documents are from the Index if the documents received by the Indexer are marked as soft-deleted.

To solve your problem, an immediate solution would be to delete the documents from the Index and then re-run the Indexer.

Better solution would be to configure your Data Source by specifying an attribute in the source documents that would indicate that the document is soft-deleted (e.g. have an attribute called `isActive` in your source documents and set it's value to `false` to indicate that the document is in soft-deleted state). You would make use of `dataDeletionDetectionPolicy` in the Data Source definition to make use of this attribute.

Here would be the steps:

1. Add an attribute in your documents in Cosmos DB that would indicate that the document is soft-deleted.
2. Configure the Data Source in Azure Search to check for this attribute for soft-delete.
3. When you receive the new documents in Cosmos DB, do not delete the old documents there. Instead change the soft-delete attribute's value to indicate that the old documents are in soft-delete state and should be removed from the Index.
4. Run the Indexer. It will delete the documents from the Index.
5. Delete the documents from Cosmos DB.

To learn more about it, please see this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-data-source.

Comment: The issue I can not modify the data. We get it as a bulk and I transfer it to Cosmos DB.

Comment: I thank you for your hlep

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Gaurav Mantri's suggestions.

You may retrieve the data with [Search Documents (Azure Cognitive Search REST API) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents) and get the doc key for the duplicate ones and proceed to [Add, Update or Delete Documents (Azure Cognitive Search REST API) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents) as needed using those REST APIs.

I suggest that you review your index schema to make sure you're using an index key that is representative of your unique doc id (such as the database doc ID). If you are getting duplicate items in your index, is because you are not using a matching value of a unique field in the source but perhaps a random id generated by the system and not one defined by you -see [Index overview - Azure Cognitive Search | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/search-what-is-an-index).